# Knex query for updating postgresql database where array type column contains a specific value

Tags: javascript, arrays, postgresql, knex.js

I have a database with an array type column and I want to update rows where the array type column contains a string. So given the string: 'my_string' I want to search the array column for 'my_string'. The following works with straight postgresql:

```
update table_name 
set column_name = value
where 'some_string' = any (array_type_column)
```

However Knex throws an error that the column 'some_string' does not exist when using the raw query builder.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
knex('table_name')
  .update('column_name', value)
  .whereRaw('? = any (??)', ['some_string', 'array_type_column'])
```

Runnable example https://runkit.com/embed/qh7okvfgfwaf